# How to redirect multiple parameter of query string using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have the following 2 links, Please some one help me

I want to redirect this page http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/category-of-mobile/any-words/?id=smob_qs&fromDate=&parts=

to another page http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/category-of-mobile/any-words/smob_qs

Note:

- `smob_qs` key is the value of the first query string
- For `category-of-mobile` keyword is fixed
- For `any-words` keyword is dynamic [only characters letters a-z or A-Z]
- For query string must removed second and third parameter
- Must keep the first query string but only value. Example like `smob_qs`

So i need `http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/category-of-mobile/any-words/smob_qs Url`

Please help me using htaccess

Comment: Thanks I have found solution link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51671411/htaccess-301-redirection-old-url-to-new-url-with-querystring-issue

Comment: RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (/category-of-mobile/any-words/)/?\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1${lc:%3}? [R=301,L,NE]