# .htaccess 301 redirection old url to new url with querystring issue

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I am facing issue with redirect below URL to new URL with query string.

`http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/product-category/subcategory/?id=TEST_TS&fromDate=&parts=`

to

`http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/product-category/subcategory/test_ts`

> I need to also query string word into `lowercase` as well.

**Note**

- `TEST_TS` keyword is the value of the first query string and must be in lowercase.
- For `product-category` keyword is fixed
- For `subcategory` keyword is dynamic [only characters letters `a-z` or `A-Z`]
- For query string must removed second and third parameter

I have also tried below code in `.htaccess` as well, But not working for me.

```
RewriteRule ^product-category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/+]+)/?id=(.*)$&%{QUERY_STRING}   product-category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/+]+)/{lc:$2$} [L]
```

Comment: lowercase conversion is only possible if you have control over Apache server config

Comment: @anubhava Yes, I have fully control over server, But I don't know how to solved this issue? As I have tried so many rules for it. But none of working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define this `RewriteMap` in your `VirtualHost` section and restart Apache:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

Then inside site root .htaccess have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (/product-category/subcategory)/?\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/${lc:%2}? [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^(product-category/subcategory)/(\w-]+)/?$ $1/?id=$2&fromDate=&parts= [L,QSA,NC]
```

`${lc:%2}` will convert value in `%2` to lowercase.

Comment: thanks for your help. above solution working fine with quite few modification. Just need to find solution for convert `uppercase` to `lowercase`. I have added `RewriteMap` in vhost file but I think its not working. Anyway thanks gor your huge help. You make my day. Thanks again :)

Comment: Check my updated for case conversion. (I missed out in my answer earlier)

Comment: Thanks again. I will surly try it with it.